# Excel-VBA doesn't copy SAS-table into Excel-sheet even if there is no error

Tags: vba, excel, sas

I want my VBA-Excel code will read a SAS-table and it will copy this SAS-table into an Excel-sheet. There are many check points. For example, first it checks if the SAS-table exists with `If fileExists(sSasTable1)`, if it exists then it continues progressing (`fileexist` is another function to check the table).

Then I implemented `errorObject` to be sure that the vba-program will show me the error details when an error occurs.

When i check with debugging, I can see that the code can find the SAS-table in the first `if-loop`, it opens the connection and recordset, but it can not execute the `rTarget.CopyFromRecordset rs` which is supposed to copy the SAS-table to the Excel-sheet. Then it goes to the `DisplayErrorInfo` instead of `rs.close`. But it doesn't give any error message.

So I don't really understand. What is the problem with the line `rTarget.CopyFromRecordset rs`? And why doesn't it show any error message?

```
Public Sub InsertSASFileIntoExcel()
   Dim YearMonth As String, SASOutput1 As String, SASOutputPath As String
   YearMonth = Sheets("Prognos").Cells(11, 2).Value
   SASOutputPath = "C:\\directories\output"
   SASOutput1 = "prognos_" & YearMonth
   Dim sSasTable1 As String: sSasTable1 = SASOutputPath & "\" & SASOutput1 & ".sas7bdat"

   If fileExists(sSasTable1) Then

      Dim rTarget1 As Range: Set rTarget1 = Sheets("Forecast_201509").Range("A1")

      Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection  ' New ADODB.Connection
      Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

      Dim errorObject As ADODB.Error  ' creates error-check object
      On Error GoTo DisplayErrorInfo

      ' Set initialization properties
      conn.Provider = "SAS.LocalProvider.1"

       conn.Open ' Open the Connection
       ' Open the Recordset
       rs.Open sSasTable1, conn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, ADODB.adCmdTableDirect

      'Populate the indata range with the contents of the SAS dataset
       rTarget.CopyFromRecordset rs  ' This line is supposed to copy the table onto the range rTarget, which is Range("A1") in the worksheet.

       rs.Close  ' Close the Recordset
       Set rs = Nothing

       conn.Close ' Close the Connection
       Set conn = Nothing

      ' In case of error, the code comes here below and it shows the description of the error.
      DisplayErrorInfo:
         For Each errorObject In rs.ActiveConnection.Errors
         Debug.Print "Description :"; errorObject.Description
         Debug.Print "Number:"; Hex(errorObject.Number)
      Next

      Else

     If giveWarning = True Then
        Call MsgBox("Warning", vbInformation, "The SAS-Table doesn't exist")
     End If

     End If

End Sub

  ' Check if a file exists
Function fileExists(s_directory As String) As Boolean

    Dim obj_fso As Object

    Set obj_fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    fileExists = obj_fso.fileExists(s_directory)

End Function
```

Comment: Until now you only have a look at the ADODB-Errors. Please put `MsgBox Err.Description` below your `DisplayErrorInfo:` outside the `For Each`...`Next`.

Comment: Thanks axel-richter , now I got an error message as `Object required`. But the code can find the SAS-table `sSasTable1`, and I checked the target also, I wrote `rTarget = 5`, then it put `5` in the target cell.

Comment: But in your code you `Dim` and `Set` `rTarget1` and not `rTarget`.

Comment: This is why you should always use `Option Explicit` :-).

Comment: Oh my Holy, Moly Goodness!!! I can't describe how embarrassing this is for me right now. I can't believe that I missed that mistake. Thanks #axel-richter